# A couple weird rigging questions

Tags: rigging, armature, clipping

Im new to almost everything in Blender except modeling so I wasn't quite sure how to get the *skirt* on my model to move in relation to the legs. I want it to be kind of in a way where if i moved a leg up, the skirt model would move with it so it doesn't clip through. But I have no idea how and don't know how to search it up.[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can give a cloth simulation to your cloth, but it may be tedious to adjust. Another solution is to create bones for the cloth in order to control it, like for example 6 x 3 vertical rows of bones all around the cloth:

[image]

Comment: thanks dude i'll try those